# Kinds of PostgreSQL naming domains

Tags: postgresql, naming, names

Which kinds of database objects in PostgreSQL form their own independent name domain, so that name collisions with objects of other kind are excluded?

Kind of database objects mean tables, schemas, views, triggers, procedures, functions, operators, variables, ...

The question is not to be confused with namespace (through schemas).

Comment: The design of the [system catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) should answer this - e.g. all relations (tables, views, etc) are stored in the same table. What's more interesting is which "name domains" are scoped to other objects, e.g. constraint names per table, and which are not, e.g. indices.

Comment: Thank you, but this list doesn't help me any further: Do user-specific types and domains form a shared name area? are they independent of functions so that I can name a function and a type the same?

Comment: `CREATE TYPE`, `CREATE DOMAIN` and `CREATE TABLE` all create a [`pg_type` entry](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html). Yes, they are independent from functions.

Comment: Ok then I try to summarize:
- type, domain, table
- trigger
- function (by the round brackets)
- procedure (I guess distinguished by 'call')
- schemes

Comment: Both procedures and functions are stored in [`pg_proc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html). If you go through these tables, look at `…typ` or `…kind` columns (like `prokind`, `typtype`, `relkind`) to find what else falls into the category.